# How to automatically disable register_hook when training model is in eval() phase in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I require to update grads of an intermediate tensor variable using the `register_hook` method. Since the variable isn't a leaf-variable, I require to add the `retain_grad()` method to it after which, I can use the `register_hook` method to alter the grads.

```
score.retain_grad()
h = score.register_hook(lambda grad: grad * torch.FloatTensor(...))
```

This works perfectly fine during the training (`model.train()`) phase. However, it gives an error during the evaluation phase (`model.eval()`).

The error:

```
File "/home/envs/darthvader/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 198, in register_hook
    raise RuntimeError("cannot register a hook on a tensor that "
RuntimeError: cannot register a hook on a tensor that doesn't require gradient
```

How could the model automatically disable the `register_hook` method when it in `eval()` phase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `score.retain_grad()` and guarding `register_hook` with if condition (`if score.requires_grad`) does the trick.

```
if score.requires_grad:
    h = score.register_hook(lambda grad: grad * torch.FloatTensor(...))
```

Originally answered by [Alban D](https://discuss.pytorch.org/u/alband/summary) [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-automatically-disable-register-hook-when-training-model-is-in-eval-phase-in-pytorch/93941).